# Correlation fitted-residuals in mixed models

Tags: mixed-model, variance, residuals

IN OLS linear models, fitted (predicted) and residuals scores are uncorrelated. I was under the impression that the same held true in mixed models. However, I have here an example model where fitted and (conditional) residual scores are correlated. Is there a theoretical justification for this to happen, or a good reference for it? I looked around but I could not find much.
From experimenting with data I found that the estimation of the residual variance (by R lm4, for instance) corresponds to the sum of the the variance of the residual scores plus the covariance between residuals scores and predicted scores. Again, I was not able to find a theoretical explanation.

Example:

```
> a <-rnorm(100,0,10)
> d<-as.data.frame(rbind(cbind(1,1:100,a),cbind(2,1:100,a)))
> names(d)<-c('cond','id','a')
> d\$y<-d\$a+d\$cond+rnorm(200,0,4)
> mm<-lmer(y~(1|id),data=d,REML = F)
> summary(mm)
```

$\ $

```
 Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['merModLmerTest']
 Formula: y ~ (1 | id)    
   Data: d

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  1414.2   1424.1   -704.1   1408.2      197 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
 -2.21522 -0.43740  0.05079  0.43243  2.06045 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 108.65   10.423  
 Residual              18.95    4.353  
 Number of obs: 200, groups: id, 100

 Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)  
 (Intercept)    1.982      1.087 100.000   1.823   0.0712 .
 ---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

cor(predict(mm),residuals(mm))
[1] 0.2725048
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: It would be true if the predicted values were the group means by `id`. But I have just checked this is not the case, and I'm somewhat surprised about that.

Comment: Hi (thanks for the comment). Predicted values are indeed not the group means by `id`, but they are a linear combination of the means (r=1). I'm surprised too.